# avidemux problems with 16.04

Tags: avidemux

So, I installed 16.04 a few days ago and had to reinstall some apps. One of them was avidemux. After I installed it from the software center I couldn't get it to work properly. It wouldn't even load a video clip before giving me an error message and closing. After trying many command prompts to purge the avidemux files, I still can't get it to reinstall from the software center... Any tips?

I posted the question a few days ago and didn't get a response.

Comment: Please don't double post. Likely the reason you did not get an answer is the lack of detail. "giving me an error message and closing" How about providing that error message? "I still can't get it to reinstall from the software center" If you try from terminal `sudo apt-get install avidemux` what is the error? Just putting "this won't work and I don't know why" does not help us to know what is wrong, please make an effort to include as much detail as possible.

Answer (score 0):

1- install getdeb package here http://www.getdeb.net/updates/Ubuntu/16.04#how_to_install

2- $ sudo apt-get update

$ sudo apt-get install avidemux2.6

Ready

Best Regard

Comment: Hi Orlando! Thanks for the info. When I try to install get-deb package it        looks like it starts to install, but I get no confirmation. A frozen window 'Waiting to install' is the only result. Restarted and tried three times. The rest of my error, trying to install avidemux:                             Package avidemux2.6 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'avidemux2.6' has no installation candidate... Still trying to work on it. Thanks again!